Extending the special function $G(n)=\prod_{k=1}^{n}k^{k^k}$ to any number
The factorial $x!$ can be extended through some simple transformation for large $N$:
$$\log((N+x)!)-\log(N!)=\sum_{k=N+1}^{N+x}\log(k)\approx x\log(N)$$
$$\implies\sum_{k=1}^{x}\log(k) + \sum_{k=x+1}^{N+x}\log(k) - \sum_{k=1}^{N}\log(k)\approx x\log(N)$$
$$\implies\log(x!) + \sum_{k=1}^{N}\log(x+k) - \sum_{k=1}^{N}\log(k)\approx x\log(N)$$
$$\implies\log(x!) \approx x\log(N) + \sum_{k=1}^{N}\log(k)-\log(x+k)$$
$$\implies\log(x!) \approx \log(N^x) + \sum_{k=1}^{N}\log\frac{k}{x+k}$$
$$\implies x!\approx N^x\prod_{k=1}^{N}\frac{k}{x+k}$$
And when $N\to\infty$, it can be rewritten as
$$x!=\Gamma(x+1)$$
Where $\Gamma(x)$ is the gamma function, the same can be applied for the hyperfactorial $H(x)$:
$$\log(H(N+x))-\log(H(N))=\sum_{k=N+1}^{N+x}\log(k^k)\approx x\frac{\log(N)(2N+x+1)+x+1}{2}$$
$$\implies\sum_{k=1}^{x}\log(k^k) + \sum_{k=x+1}^{N+x}\log(k^k) - \sum_{k=1}^{N}\log(k^k)\approx x\frac{\log(N)(2N+x+1)+x+1}{2}$$
$$\implies\log(H(x)) + \sum_{k=1}^{N}\log\left((x+k)^{x+k}\right) - \sum_{k=1}^{N}\log(k^k)\approx x\frac{\log(N)(2N+x+1)+x+1}{2}$$
$$\implies\log(H(x)) \approx x\frac{\log(N)(2N+x+1)+x+1}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^{N}\log(k^k)-\log\left((x+k)^{x+k}\right)$$
$$\implies\log(H(x)) \approx x\frac{\log(N)(2N+x+1)+x+1}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^{N}\log\frac{k^k}{(x+k)^{x+k}}$$
$$\implies H(x)\approx \exp\left(\frac{x(x+1)}{2}\right)\sqrt{N^{2Nx+x^2+x}}\prod_{k=1}^{N}\frac{k^k}{(x+k)^{x+k}}$$
$$\implies H(x)=K(x+1)\qquad\text{when $N\to\infty$}$$
Where $K(x)$ is the K-function.
Question: can the same be applied for the function $G(x)=\prod_{k=1}^{x}k^{k^k}$ so that it is defined for any number in $\mathbb{C}$?
Edit: I tried the Euler-Maclaurin formula and got this
$$G(x)=\exp\left(\int_1^{\max(x,x+1-\lfloor x\rfloor)}t^t\ln tdt+\frac{\max(x,x+1-\lfloor x\rfloor)^{\max(x,x+1-\lfloor x\rfloor)}\ln \max(x,x+1-\lfloor x\rfloor)}{2}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{B_{2k}}{2k}\sum_{h=0}^{2k-1}\frac{1}{(2k-1-h)!}\left(\ln^{(2k-1-h)}(\max(x,x+1-\lfloor x\rfloor))\max(x,x+1-\lfloor x\rfloor)^{\max(x,x+1-\lfloor x\rfloor)-h}\sum_{i=0}^{h}\max(x,x+1-\lfloor x\rfloor)^i\sum_{j=0}^{i}\left[\sum_{q=0}^{h-i}\frac{s(q+j,j)}{(q+j)!}\binom{j}{h-i-q}\right]\frac{\ln^{i-j}\max(x,x+1-\lfloor x\rfloor)}{(i-j)!}-\ln^{(2k-1-h)}(1)\sum_{i=0}^{h}\sum_{q=0}^{h-i}\frac{s(q+i,i)}{(q+i)!}\binom{i}{h-i-q}\right)-\sum_{k=0}^{-\lfloor x\rfloor}(x+k+1)^{x+k+1}\ln(x+k+1)\right)$$
Edit 2: the Euler-Maclaurin formula above did not interpolates the original function because the error term $R_{\infty}\neq 0$

@Maxime for large $N$ the approximation becomes accurate

@Maxime The first one, for instance, yields $$
x! = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{N \to  + \infty } N^x \prod\limits_{k = 1}^N {\frac{k}{{k + x}}} .
$$ The right-hand side is convergent for $x\in \mathbb{C}$, $x\neq -1,-2,-3,\ldots$ and yields an extension of the factorial. It is easy to show that this definition yields $$
x! = {\rm e}^{\gamma x} \prod\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{\rm e}^{x/k} }}{{1 + x/k}}}
$$ under the same constraints on $x$.
